# URLs generate with wrong host and port when running Rails on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a few services glued together with Docker Compose. The main service is a Rails app in its own container. It sits behind an Nginx proxy, also in its own container. (Other services sit behind Nginx too, but that's immaterial.)

In `docker-compose.yml`, I've assigned the name `web` to the Rails service. Thus, `web` is the container's hostname within the Docker network. The Rails container exposes port 3000. So my Nginx reverse-proxy config looks like this:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://web:3000;
}
```

This works great, except for one problem. From the perspective of the Rails app, all requests are to `web:3000`. Because Rails generates internal URLs based on the request's hostname and port, I end up with URLs to `web:3000` in the responses.

For example, if I put this in a template:

```
<%= link_to 'Admin', admin_url %>
```

I get this in the rendered HTML:

```
<a href="http://web:3000/admin">Admin</a>
```

I understand why this is happening, but I'm not sure about the best practice for fixing it. I'd rather not hard-code a port and hostname into the Rails code if I can avoid it.

This seems like it would be a universal problem with Docker and Rails, so I'm guessing others have encountered it. Ideas?

**Edit.** I solved part of the problem by having Nginx pass the original host name through to Rails, like this:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://web:3000;
}
```

However, Rails still doesn't see the external port, or the protocol (`http` vs `https`).

**Edit 2.** As requested in a comment, here's `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      # For flexibility, I'd like to be able to set whatever host-side
      # port I want. E.g. 5000:80.
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ssl-certs:/ssl-certs
      - ssl-webroot:/ssl-webroot
      - type: bind
        source: ./nginx.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        read_only: true
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    command: --version
    volumes:
      - ssl-certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ssl-webroot:/ssl-webroot
  web:
    build: ./rails
    volumes:
      - gems:/gems
    environment:
      - GEM_HOME=/gems
      - MYSQL_DOCKER_HOST
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_DB=myapp_dev
      - MYSQL_TEST_DB=myapp_test
volumes:
  gems:
  ssl-certs:
  ssl-webroot:
```

Comment: Show me your compose file

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: Try adding these two directives also in your proxy_pass block `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: @rlkw1024 did you finally solve the issue? I'm having the same issue, but setting `proxy_set_header  Host $host; proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` didn't solve the issue